# Is there anyway to access/modify an array using a string that contains the name of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Let's say we have a couple arrays called "one", "two", and "three". Is there any way to access/modify the arrays using a string that contains the name of the array? For example,

```
int one[n];
int two[n];
int three[n];
string str = "one";
// str can be "one", "two", or "three"
// I wanna access/modify whatever array that str is the name of
```

Comment: If you’re trying to do something like this, there’s a better way to do it instead. (It sounds like an XY problem.) What’s the higher-level intention that you think this is a solution for?

Comment: Are those arrays all of the same type? Please show the declaration of at least one of the arrays.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy: I'd suggest that if you're writing an interpreter for a programming language, this can be a perfectly reasonable design.

Comment: Only if you design algorithms, write code and create/use relevant data structures.   There isn't such a mapping between strings (stored in arrays) and the names of variables built into the core language of C++.   Depending on your needs, you might be able to use some types (e.g. a map) or collections of functionality (e.g. algorithms) from the standard library to implement what you seek.    But no part of the standard library is specifically designed to do what you seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. But also yes, you'll have to do write the code to map from the name as a string to the array you want that name to refer to.

A simple version would be to use an `std::unordered_map` for the task:

```cpp
  std::vector<int> one, two, three;

  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int> &> names {
    { "one", one },
    { "two", two },
    { "three", three }
  };

  std::string arrayName;
  std::cin >> arrayName;

  auto pos = names.find(arrayName);
  if (pos == names.end())
      std::cerr << "name not found\n";
  else {
      auto & currentArray = pos->second;

      // do something with the selected vector:
      currentArray.push_back(1);
  }
```

This isn't something that arises terribly often, but it can at times. One obvious possibility is when you're writing an interpreter for some programming language.

In such a case, you'll typically have a *slightly* different structure though. You'll have something like this:

```cpp
class Integer { /* ... */ };
class String { /* ... */ };
// ...

std::variant<Integer, String /* ... */ } Variable;

std::unordered_map<std::string, Variable> symbol_table;
```

So with this, we specify a class to model each type in the target language, and then have a symbol table mapping from names to objects.

But there are also a few languages that only really have variables of one type, and to the extent they support other types at all, it's by converting from that one type to whatever else on the fly, based on how they're used. In such a case, you'd probably store all your variables as objects of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to access/modify an array using a string that contains the name of the array?

**No.** Variable names are there for the benefit of the programmer; by the time the code is compiled and executed, a variable's name no longer exists.